# Want to move file over network (not copy)

Tags: mv

I would like to move file on network [Linux].

This is not working:

```
mv {file} user@machine:/
```

How can I do this?

And I prefer not using scp command to first copy and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync with the option

```
--remove-source-files
```